# Github Desktop: Why the inconsistent merge commit message between Window and Mac version

Tags: git, github-for-windows, github-desktop

So I'm using the `Update from [branch]` button to merge.

On Windows I get this kind of commit message:

> Merge remote-tracking branch 'refs/remotes/origin/dev'

Then on Mac, I get this kind:

> Merge branch 'dev'

What gives? Is there a way to make the application to use a specific one?

**UPDATE**: here's my output from `git branch -avv`

```
  dev                   4bcfc85 [origin/dev] Added foo.txt
* master                83ed153 [origin/master: ahead 2] Merge remote-tracking branch 'refs/remotes/origin/dev'
  remotes/origin/dev    4bcfc85 Added foo.txt
  remotes/origin/master 5c81201 Merge branch 'refs/heads/dev'
```

**UPDATE-2**: output above is same in both cases.

Comment: Are you using the latest version on Windows?

Comment: Yeah the `About` tab says i'm up to date

Comment: Since this is a question about "GitHub Desktop" (which I don't use) I can't answer it, but I'll note that both of those merge messages are not very good.

Comment: @torek yeh I'd probably agree with that statement

Comment: I am not using github-desktop, but it seems to me that the preconditions weren't the same on both systems. I think that on the first system you never checked out the branch `dev`, but on the second you did. Ask if this does not make any sense to you.

Comment: @AnimiVulpis you mean checked out or fetched?

Comment: I think he means "checked out". It seems to me too that in the first case you are referring to a remote only branch, and in the second case to a local branch (possibly tracking a remote one)

Comment: @CarloBellettini Exactly what I am thinking. It could be that github-desktop tries to hide the difference between a local branch tracking a remote branch and a remote-branch (which basically exists as a **read-only** local branch, which is sometimes confusing for people ^^)

Comment: So in the first case (Windows), I created the `dev` branch locally off of `master`, added a file, committed and pushed, then checked out `master` and clicked the `Update from dev` button. To be sure, when I merge from console with `git merge dev`, I do get the shorter message from the second case.

Comment: If you created `dev` from `master`, is it the same state (hash) as `origin/dev`? A lot of guessing here right now. Maybe just edit your question to include the (shortened) output of `git branch -avv` which should show you all your branches (local and remote) with their defined upstreams and their relation to those upstream branches.

Comment: @AnimiVulpis thanks for checking this out so far, I've updated my question with this output

Comment: Sorry to ask you another thing. Could you do the same again on the other machine and update your question to include both outputs? But from what I am seeing here I think there is no _easy_ way of specifying which message (e.g. branch) to use.

Comment: The output is the same, so somehow in the second case, Github Desktop is figuring the branch just fine. I'll have to test this out on another Windows machine to confirm if the issue is OS specific